# Get Int-Array from Grayscale BitmapImage

Tags: c#, arrays, image

I have a grayscale `BitmapImage` in C# and want to get a simple `Int[,]` array with the image data, so I can simply access the values of the image just by e.g. `Image[10,20]` and get back values from 0-255 or however many bit my image has.

However, there is no `GetData` function or anything on `BitmagImage` - how do I get such an array?

Comment: "_there is no GetData function or anything on BitmagImage_" Untrue. Have you looked at the documentation for _BitmapImage_? The method you are looking for might not be called `GetData` (and my name might not be `John`, but that doesn't mean i don't exist), but there is a method that allows copying of the pixel data into an array. Now, before using this method that is not being called John, er... i mean, GetData, you might want to make sure that your BitmapImage is in the desired pixel format (i.e. 8bpp, if i understand you correctly)

Comment: Small addition to my previous comment: Since you want get values in the range 0..255 (which correlates with 8bpp pixel format), it would be easier for you to work with byte arrays. When using int arrays where each int should be one pixel, you would want to work with 32bpp pixel formats, as otherwise you cannot copy pixel data into the array _directly_. However, 32bpp means that you would then have to deal with color and alpha channel components, with a grayscale value of for example 0x23 represented by an integer like 0x232323FF (using BGRA32 pixel format here in this example).